# Speed-optimized loop through single cells of a RasterStack object

Tags: r, parallel-processing, raster

I'm working with two RasterStack objects, each one consisting of ten layers representing single time steps.

```
# Mock data
pred.rst.stck <- do.call("stack", lapply(seq(10), function(i) {
  pred.rst <- raster(nrows = 15, ncols = 15, xmn= 0, xmx = 10, ymn = 0, ymx = 10)
  pred.rst[] <- rnorm(225, 50, 10)
  return(pred.rst)
})
resp.rst.stck <- do.call("stack", lapply(seq(10), function(i) {
  resp.rst <- raster(nrows = 10, ncols = 10, xmn = 0, xmx = 10, ymn = 0, ymx = 10)
  resp.rst[] <- rnorm(100, 50, 10)
  return(resp.rst)
})
```

`pred.rst.stck` serves as set of predictor variables and `resp.rst.stck` as set of response variables. For each single cell of the predictor RasterStack, I'd like to fit a linear model on each cell of the response RasterStack, extract the corresponding R-squared per fitted model and sum those up. To cut a long story short, here's my fastest approach so far using R's `parallel` package:

```
# Parallelization
library(parallel)
n.cores <- detectCores()
clstr <- makePSOCKcluster(n.cores)

# Extract cell values from RasterStack objects
pred.vals <- getValues(pred)
resp.vals <- getValues(resp)
clusterExport(clstr, c("pred.vals", "resp.vals"))

# Loop through all predictor cells
rsq.sums <- parLapply(clstr, seq(nrow(pred.vals)), function(i) {
  # For each predictor cell, loop through all response cells, 
  # fit linear model, extract and sum up single R-squared 
  do.call("sum", lapply(seq(nrow(resp.vals)), function(j) {
    summary(lm(resp.vals[j, ] ~ pred.vals[i, ]))$r.squared
  }))
})
```

Although `parLapply` performs much better compared to ordinary `lapply`, I am wondering if there's an elegant way to speed up the whole procedure. Any suggestions?

Cheers,
Florian

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few tricks you can try. I can't quite understand the way you are going about creating linear models, but the `r.squared` you are calculating from your linear model is equivalent to the square of Pearson's correlation coefficient (`cor` in R with default arguments) which is far quicker to compute than a linear model.

Compare these two functions using your data:

```
# Finding r.squared using a lm
f1 <- function(n){summary(lm(resp.vals[n,] ~pred.vals[n,]))$r.squared}
# Finding r.squared using Pearson's
f2 <- function(n){ cor(resp.vals[n,],pred.vals[n,])^2}

# Both give the same result
f1(1)
[1] 0.0009032986
f2(1)
[1] 0.0009032986
```

And in terms of timing a single call of these functions:

```
require(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark( f1(1) , f2(1) )
Unit: microseconds
  expr      min        lq   median        uq      max neval
 f1(1) 2009.328 2037.0680 2071.045 2124.9225 4102.079   100
 f2(2)   73.075   77.7365   84.690   89.7215 5485.368   100
```

So you should be able to cut your processing time 25-fold by using `cor` instead of `lm`.

A quick system-time comparison exchanging the original function for use of `cov()^2` shows this to be the case:

```
#Using cov()
   user  system elapsed 
  0.013   0.002   1.085

#Using lm()
   user  system elapsed 
  0.159   0.028  26.334
```